# How to write django code inside css style tag to link images from static directory

Tags: css, django, tags, styles, django-staticfiles

I want to write Django code into CSS style tag in HTML elements in order to get images from static directory. here is my original code

```
<a href="single.html" class="img" style="background-image: url(images/image_1.jpg);"></a>
```

i tried with the below code

```
<a href="single.html" class="img" style="background-image: {% static 'images/image_1.jpg' %};"></a>
```

but this isn't worked for me, how can i solve this problem?
NB: i used {% load static %} to load all static files, css and js works fine but i became failed to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Add These Code In Your settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myproject/static')
]


# Media settings
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Then Add These Code In Your project urls.py

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Then add this line to your html

```
style="background-image: url({%static 'images/person_1.jpg' %});"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if in your root `project/settings.py` has something like this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
```

and then, in your root `project/urls.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [...] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

To be sure, make sure you restart your server after these changes.

Answer (score 0):

In settings.py add this

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

try to convert style tags in this manner

```
style ="background-image:url(images/image_1.jpg)"
```

TO

```
style ="background-image:url('/static/images/image_1.jpg')"
```